# Is it right way for handling exceptions using Apache ExceptionUtils.getRootCause?

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible, that below condition in "My code" will be fulfilled(true)? I belive that no, beacuse `getRootCause` returns object casted to `Throwable`. So it should check, if `Throwable` is a subtype of `MyOwnException`, which is not true. So, in general, it is wrong way to use `getRootCause` to handle exceptions, is not it?

**MyOwnException part**

```
public class MyOwnException extends Exception {
   // ....
}
```

**Apache's ExceptionUtils.getRootCause**

```
public static Throwable getRootCause(Throwable throwable) {
    List list = getThrowableList(throwable);
    return (list.size() < 2 ? null : (Throwable)list.get(list.size() - 1)); 
}
```

**My code**

```
try {
    // do something
} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        Throwable exc = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e);
        if (exc instanceof MyOwnException) {
            // do something
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instanceof` will check against the actual run-time type of an object instance. It does not matter what the declared compile-time type of the variable that holds the object is.

So your condition works: If the root cause is a `MyOwnException` then your `if` block's body will execute.